# Using an "extern" global before it is properly initialized

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to determine if there is an elegant solution to this issue.

Say I have a global defined in some header:

Constants.h:

```
extern NSString *someGlobal;
```

And then I wish to use this global in some other class:

Foo.m

```
NSString *localVariable = someGlobal;
```

This all works just fine if I initialize the global like this:

Constants.m:

```
NSString *someGlobal = @"Some String Literal";
```

But lets say I need to initialize the global to something that isn't a compile-time constant. In such cases I typically do this:

Constants.m:

```
@implementation Constants

+ (void)initialize {
    someGlobal = ... // some non-trivial initialization
}

@end
```

Now I have a potential problem in `Foo.m`. If no reference has been made to the `Constants` class when I try to use `someGlobal`, the result is `nil`. A workaround is to do:

Foo.m (or in some app startup code):

```
[Constants class];
```

That will trigger the `initialize` method of the `Constants` class and `someGlobal` will be properly initialized. As long as this is done before any runtime use of `someGlobal`, things work fine.

Is there a better way to initialize extern globals with non-compile time constants without the need to call code such as `[Constants class`] at app startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no better way. Logically, if some piece of code must execute before a variable is intialized, you have to take steps to make sure that happens.

You could arrange the flow of your program's code so as to guarantee that the `Constants` class get initialized before any other piece of code executes which needs it. For example, by tweaking the order in which things are initialized in your program and following the order of code execution from `main()` on down to prove to yourself that it works. But short of that (and the safest thing in any case), you would use your technique to force it to be made valid right before you use it.

Comment: Thanks. This is my current approach.

Answer (score 4):

A more idiomatic way in Objective-C is using a *singleton* instead of multiple globals. Here is how:

```
@interface Globals
@property (readwrite,nonatomic) NSString *myString;
@property (readwrite,nonatomic) int myInt;
+(Globals*) instance;
@end

+(Globals*) instance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static Globals *inst;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        inst = [[Globals alloc] init];
        inst.myString = @"Some String Literal";
        inst.myInt = 42;
    });
    return inst;
}
```

Now you can use your globals like this:

```
NSLog(@"Global string: %@", [Globals instance].myString);
NSLog(@"Global string: %d", [Globals instance].myInt);
```

Comment: I agree that's a nicer way to do it if you're willing to give up the "plain" C variable.

Comment: This is a viable approach in some cases but I was hoping for a more general solution. The reality is that I have a project with 100s of classes and several classes define extern globals. It wouldn't be appropriate to collect globals from scattered classes into one singleton or to define a whole bunch of singletons just to deal with  a couple of non-trival constants. But this is good to keep in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like dasblinkenlight's answer, this may not be exactly what you are looking for but it's another approach.

I would make class methods that returns the value you are looking for like this:

```
+(NSString *)someConstant {
    static NSString *constant;
    if(constant == nil)
        constant = //your initialization here;
    return constant;
}
```

Then where you need to use it just call `[Constants someConstant];`

*Other random thoughts:*
A constant that isn't some compile time value isn't really what extern variables are for and this method insures that the variable is initialized every time you use it. The class using the constant has to know about your class anyway or it wouldn't have imported its header file