# Extern Variable initialization

Tags: objective-c, extern

In my project I am working on it since last 6 months , i was using #define to define all URL in a FileManager class.but Now I came to know that I have to use two different URL depend on condition so dynamically I can not change #define values.so I decided to Use extern variables in FileManager class instead of #define.

as
          in interface file

```
       extern NSString *Url;
       extern NSString *loginUrl;
```

in m file

```
        @implementation UrlManager
        + (void) initialize{
        Url=@"http://xxxxxxxxxx.com";
        loginUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",Url,@"/ipad.php?method=audLogin&username="];
             }
```

but when I am importing URLManager.h , and using loginUrl, still its null , please help me how can I initialize extern variables so that I can use these in app.

Comment: In the .m file, do you have the lines: `NSString *Url;` and `NSString *loginUrl;` before the `@implementation` line? Are you using ARC or MRC?

Comment: Side note - why not initialize `loginURL` this way: `loginUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/ipad.php?method=audLogin&username=", Url];`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035932/using-an-extern-global-before-it-is-properly-initialized for a possible cause of your issue. The last paragraph of the answer by "bbum" mentions this.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you have a URL, use NSURL to reference it.

Secondly, name your globals consistently and descriptively.  `AliRootURL` and `AliLoginURL` would be descriptive and has a prefix (`Ali` -- change it) to make it easy to recognize.

Finally, don't use globals at all.   Instead, have class methods on your `URLManager` class (which really should be prefixed, too) that return the URLs:

```
@interface AliURLManager:NSObject
+(NSURL*)rootURL; // no need to prefix methods in your custom classes
+(NSURL*)loginURL;
@end
```

That way, you can implement those methods to initially return URLs directly:

```
+(NSURL*)rootURL
{
     // use a static and dispatch_once() if you want only one instance
     return [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foobar.com/"];
}
+(NSURL*)loginURL
{
     NSURL* root = [self rootURL];
     NSURL* loginURL;
     ... calculate loginURL here... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718429/creating-url-query-parameters-from-nsdictionary-objects-in-objectivec)
    return loginURL;
}
```

That way, you could easily refactor your code to, say, read URLs from the defaults database or have a different configuration for development.

---

Bummer -- but I can understand the desire to not change lots of files.  Should be search and replaceable, though (at least, would be if your variables were a bit more descriptive).

If you are going to initialize the globals via `+initialize`, you need to ensure that the class is tickled.   Add `[URLManager class];` to your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

Comment: No I cant use methods now ,as i want to change only one file , doing this I have to change 100 of files